# How do I display the value of a jQuery variable for testing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a slider that uses jQuery. Some elements of the slider are working correctly, but there is a problem that I am trying to troubleshoot with some of the code. To test it I would like to be able to display the values of the variables in the statement.

Here is the code block I am working with:

```
$('.marquee_nav a.marquee_nav_item').click(function(){
        $('.marquee_nav a.marquee_nav_item').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var navClicked = $(this).index();
        var marqueeWidth = $('.marquee_container').width();
        var distanceToMove = marqueeWidth * (-1);
        var newPhotoPosition = (navClicked * distanceToMove) + 'px';
        var newCaption = $('.marquee_panel_caption').get(navClicked); 

        $(' .marquee_photos').animate({left: newPhotoPosition}, 1000);
        });
```

I added a div called 'test' where I would like to display the values of the variables to make sure they are returning expected results:

```
<div class="test"><p>The value is: <span></span></p></div>
```

For example, to test the values, I inserted this into the statement above:

```
$('.test span').append(marqueeWidth);
```

However, I don't get any results. What is the correct way to include a test inside that code block to make sure I am getting the expected results?

Thanks.

Comment: console.log(value); then press f12 in FireFox or Chrome to bring up the web inspector and developer console. All logs are under the 'Console' tab.

Comment: What's a jQuery variable? Never heard about it.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `console.log` to see your variables?

Comment: Use the console, eg `console.log(marqueeWidth)`. Press F12 to see the console in your browser. This has the benefit of not affecting the DOM which could alter the error you see.

Comment: u could use alert function

Comment: @lordkain It's really amazing to debug a page with alerts popping up all the time.

Comment: Whatever you learn from this question, remember this: Never debug with `alert()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use [JavaScript's `console` functions](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to log your variables within your browser's console.

```
var myVar = 123;
console.log(myVar, "Hello, world!");
```

[image: Example Console Image]

If you're unsure how to open the console within your browser, see: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: I use `window.console&&console.log(...)` to help IE

Comment: I always do something like console.log(typeof myVar, myVar) for debugging and really helps a lot when something isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

`append` is used to append either an HTML string, a DOM element, an array of DOM elements, or a jQuery element. Since you are just trying to show a number (`marqueeWidth`), you probably want to set the `text` of the span instead:

```
$('.test span').text(marqueeWidth);
```

Also, is there a particular reason why you don't just use the console? It may be worth reading over a [Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) walkthrough.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following.

```
$('.test span').html(marqueeWidth);
```

However doing a `console.log(yourvariable);` or `alert(yourvariable);` is better.